# Could not roll back JPA transaction; javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking" exceptions?

Tags: jpa, persistence

What events cause "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException - Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking" exceptions?

Comment: You should try to provide more information on what you are trying to do, at what point you get the error, etc. Perhaps a full stack trace and some code/config files would help too...

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error with spring and Jpa.
The problem was with disconnection to Mysql database in case of timeout. I didn't use application during the night and in the morning I got the same error. When you inactive, spring do nothing and it get timeout.
To prevent it you can add into `application.properties` next lines:

```
spring.datasource.connection-test-query="SELECT 1"
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
```

Now it works fine.
Also additional info from [Virtustilus blog](http://virtustilus.ru/) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction is a XA-Transaction (distributed) then one of the participants might have rejected the rollback.